# Unsuscribe user in Cloudpages with landingpage

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

I'm getting crazy with this "technology"... there is not so much documentation about this... and I think that asking here is the best

I'm trying to make a landing page for unsuscribe users.

I got a link personalized to a user in my email list which is actived... my purpose is load a landing page with a form and submit button that unsuscribe that user.

I've been trying and testing so much but I don't know how to achieve this (easy task I think)

I read a lot about this, see some code with EventUnsub and so, but I do not know even where (and how) I should write code for submitting.

When I click link from email, It loads my landing page, but (is it posible to read user is this link about? What user is related to this link? How can I read this?

Is this possible?

As you may note, I'm starting with cloudpages.

Comment: You'll want to log an unsub event, which has been [discussed several times around here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmarketing-cloud%5D+unsub+event) already.

Comment: Where can I find some tutorial to start with cloudPages? Somebody knows?